# disable ngRoute option in specific links

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have 2 links which require different pages using ngRoute

```
<a href="#home">Home</a>
<a href="#profile">Profile</a>
```

When profile link is clicked a page appears which have bootstrap tabs

```
 <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs profiletab" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#tab1" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#tab2" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab2</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#tab3" aria-controls="images" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab3</a></li>    
  </ul>

 <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
        Tab 1 data    
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
        Tab2 data

    </div>   
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="tab3">
        Tab 3 data

    </div>
</div>
```

If i click on the tabs its showing blank page instead of opening the corresponding tabs
How to disable ngRoute option in bootstrap tabs?
My angular configuration is shown below

```
var app = angular.module("medg", ['ngRoute'] );

 // configure our routes
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

        // route for the home page
        .when('/home', {
            templateUrl : 'pages/home.html',
            controller  : 'mainController'
        })
        .when('/profile', {
            templateUrl : 'pages/profile.html',
            controller  : 'ProfileController'
        })
        .otherwise('/');

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should look the approach the other way, it's more how you can disable the link in the tab?

it could be done by assigning a target blank element, all target=blank will be ignored by the angular router:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs profiletab" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#tab1" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#tab2" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" target="_blank">Tab2</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#tab3" aria-controls="images" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" target="_blank">Tab3</a></li>    
  </ul>
```

or using a ng-disabled and creating an expression evaluating the route name

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs profiletab" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#tab1" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a   ng-disabled="someroute === 'home'" href="#tab2" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab2</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#tab3" ng-disabled="someroute === 'profile'" aria-controls="images" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab3</a></li>    
</ul>
```

set a route name in your resolve method in the router something like this:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

        // route for the home page
        .when('/home', {
            templateUrl : 'pages/home.html',
            controller  : 'mainController',
            resolve:{
                someroute:function(){
                    return 'home';
                }
            }
        })
        .when('/profile', {
            templateUrl : 'pages/profile.html',
            controller  : 'ProfileController',
            resolve:{
                someroute:function(){
                    return 'profile';
                }
            }
        })
        .otherwise('/');
});
```

in you controller

```
app.controller("myController", function (someroute) {
    $scope.someroute = someroute;
});
```

if you don't like to set custom names to the routes. you can also ask for the route name in the controller like

```
app.controller("myController", function ($location) {
    $scope.someroute = $location.path(); // '/Home'
});
```

Comment: target="blank" option is working fine. but second option is not working. its setting the disabled="disabled" on the links but its not working.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `href="#tab1"`, use `data-target="#tab1"`. Worked for me

Comment: Perfect! As simple as it is!